# How to sum up country counts to display number per continent

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a PHP application to display registrants statistics and I have a MySQL table already filled with registrants data. The columns are Name, Organization and Country *(there's no Continent column)*.

How can I display the number of registrants from each **continent**?

Comment: How do you expect to query registrants from continent if you don't have a continent column

Comment: if u dont have `continent column` then how can u get this?

Comment: i suggest u to get the continent table with the help of google... and in this table u must have country, then u can join them

Comment: @akshithDayanand A continent column would be useful, but Megha could also make a seperate table containing a country and continent column and JOIN the two tables.

Comment: country column is integer or varchar?? are u saving numeric country code or complete country name?

Comment: IMHO this is something you should figure out yourself, by working through some basic SQL tutorials. This site is not a place to teach the basics.

Comment: Thanks! I thought of adding up country counts using PHP like if the country is UK, France etc then Europe is this much. I will try, thanks again!

Comment: @devpro, the complete country name. Thanks!

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yeah, either way you need to have continent data stored in database.

Comment: @Megha My suggestion would be to create a column for continent in the users/ registration table and then query it using `GROUP BY continent`

Comment: Thank you @akshithDayanand, I will work as you suggested.

Comment: Although @akshithDayanand gave you a general direction, the question is poor because you have not included any relevant details. Like having the data available. In most cases you can not just make up a new column and expect it to be filled.

Comment: one more solution,  u can create 2 tables for contenent and country

Comment: @ArnoldVanDerDrift, sorry, the registration data is already there, so I thought of creating a separate table with country and continent columns then querying the two tables on country names match and group by continent. Thank you!

Comment: explore this https://gist.github.com/nobuti/3816985, use both tables in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all,** i suggest you to normalize your table structure, for normalization, you must need a country table which having all information related to country included `continent`.

**Explore this:** https://gist.github.com/nobuti/3816985 You will find a country table.

**Solution with your example:**

In your structure, you must need 2 tables here, one for `continents` and second one is `countries`

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `continents` (
  `code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Continent code',
  `name` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
  `code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Two-letter country code (ISO 3166-1 alpha-2)',
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'English country name',
  `full_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Full English country name',
  `iso3` CHAR(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Three-letter country code (ISO 3166-1 alpha-3)',
  `number` SMALLINT(3) ZEROFILL NOT NULL COMMENT 'Three-digit country number (ISO 3166-1 numeric)',
  `continent_code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
  KEY `continent_code` (`continent_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_countries_continents` FOREIGN KEY (`continent_code`) REFERENCES `continents` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Side Note:** Get INSERT query from https://gist.github.com/nobuti/3816985

After this, you can use `INNER JOIN` to solve your problem, something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total, co.name 
FROM registrants rg
INNER JOIN countries cc ON cc.name = rg.country
INNER JOIN continents co ON co.code = cc.continent_code
GROUP BY co.name
```

**Now,** you can get number of registrants GROUP with continent name.